# How to generate a shape with 3 faces in three.js

Tags: three.js, 3d

I am trying to generate a shape like this, 3d rectangle with a transparent face or just 3 panels in a 3d way.

I am new to three.js and I wanted to know if this is possible and if you could guide me.

Thanks a lot!

You can find an image of what I want to generate here:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/h0ja7.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an option, you can do it this way:

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
camera.position.set(2, 2, 3);
camera.lookAt(scene.position);
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
renderer.setClearColor(0x404040);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var contorls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

var boxGeom = new THREE.BoxGeometry(2, 1, 1);
var mat1 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  color: "red",
  side: THREE.DoubleSide
});
var mat2 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  color: "aqua",
  side: THREE.DoubleSide,
  transparent: true,
  opacity: 0.5
});
var boxMat = [mat1, mat1, null, null, mat2, null];
var box = new THREE.Mesh(boxGeom, boxMat);

scene.add(box);

render();

function render() {
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hey, this is what I needed for now:) Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sorry, now I have accepted it. Do you know if It's possible to add extra panels on different angles? Thanks!

Comment: @Alex1231 Sorry, I’m afraid I didn’t get what you mean with panels and angles. Could you create a new question with more information about it?

Comment: Hey, I have posted it here if you have time to check it out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51552323/manipulate-shape-size-angle-and-material-in-three-js